# Does putting a Portable Hole into a Bag of Holding allow a saving throw?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, magic-items

Does putting the Portable Hole into the Bag of Holding grant a saving throw or is it a guaranteed rip to another plane? I want to use this to derail a game with a group I don't like, but I need to know if it is saveless or not. (If so I want try to manipulate the rest of the party into a position where they wouldn't be able to save.)

Comment: I'm going to downvote this simply because it isn't a useful question. This kind of self-destructive use of portable holes is never going to be used in a real campaign.

Comment: @Theik On the contrary: a more productive use for the information could be for a sacrifice play to defeat a powerful enemy or overwhelming group and save the rest of the party from certain death, for example. If the extraneous jerkishness that doesn't actually add anything (i.e. everything after the first sentence) was removed from the question, it could be good.

Answer (score 17):

No saving throw of any kind is described for the effect of putting a *portable hole* into a *bag of holding*, so there isn't one. This will work, all things being equal.

However, this is a terrible idea. If you hate the people in a group so much, there are few things you can do that are worse than just walking out on them. Even if you manage to TPK the party or otherwise derail the game, once the game collapses (and you're not invited back), the GM can simply retcon the whole thing and continue without you, while they all congratulate themselves on being rid of that weirdo who tried to wreck the game for no reason. They're not hostage to whatever scheme you cook up, because imagination.

All you'll have accomplished is being visibly petty, like an impotent imp shaking their tiny little fists. That doesn't feel good. It feels much better to smugly leave a group and [have fun by going and playing with people you like instead](https://bankuei.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/fun-now-manifesto-reposting/).

Answer (score 6):

No save is described, so there isn't any.